# excel pointing to a cell when the number of the cell is calculated

Tags: excel, pointers, cell

**how do I point to a cell when i calculate the number of the cell any time diffrently?**

**exemple:**

```
='sheet1'!$F(C4+8)
```

In case that in C4 there is "2" then excel will read it as

```
='sheet1'!$F10
```

**OR**

```
='sheet1'!$F(Y9*8+X4:E1)
```

and in case of Y9=2 X4=32 E1=16

THEN excel will execute:

```
='sheet1'!$F18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `INDIRECT()`:

```
=INDIRECT("'sheet1'!$F"&C4+8)
```

`INDIRECT` takes a text and converts it to a range. You can put formulas and other calculations inside.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to use `INDEX` rather than INDIRECT, i.e.

`=INDEX(sheet1!$F:$F,C4+8)`

You can replace C4+8 with any calculation that returns a row number

That has two advantages over INDIRECT - it isn't "volatile" and because the range isn't text it can adjust if you want to delete columns or copy across etc.